# Turn on SSL for FTP connection via Arm template

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to enable SSL for a new FTP API Connection that is being deployed via an ARM template

[image]

I have figured out the options for the others but I cant see how to tick enable SSL?

```
"variables": {
      "ftpisssl": "true",
      "ftpisBinaryTransport": "true",
      "ftpdisableCertificateValidation": "true",
      "ftpCloseConnectionAfterRequestCompletion": "true"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "name": "[parameters('ftpConnectionAPIName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('ftpConnectionAPIName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "serverAddress": "[parameters('ftpServerAddress')]",
          "userName": "[parameters('ftpUsername')]",
          "password": "[parameters('ftpPassword')]",
          "isSsl": "[variables('ftpisssl')]",
          "isBinaryTransport": "[variables('ftpisBinaryTransport')]",
          "disableCertificateValidation": "[variables('ftpdisableCertificateValidation')]",
          "closeConnectionAfterRequestCompletion": "[variables('ftpCloseConnectionAfterRequestCompletion')]"
        },
```

I have tried both isssl and isSsl

How do I do this?

Paul

Comment: I opened the JSON view of an existing item in our Portal and it is referenced as "isSSL". Let me know if that works and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @JoelCochran that worked thanks maybe was a combination I didnt try thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any specific documentation on this, so I examined our Resources in the Azure Portal and found an FTP API Connection.

From the Resource panel, click on the "JSON View" link in the upper right hand corner to see the ARM configuration:

[image]

In the *properties* object is the *parameterValues* object:

[image]

This shows the name as "isSSL".